# SQL to Mongo Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

Hi I want to change my sql query to mongo aggregation.

```
select c.year, c.minor_category, count(c.minor_category) from Crime as c 
group by c.year, c.minor_category having c.minor_category = (
    Select cc.minor_category from Crime as cc where cc.year=c.year group by
    cc.minor_category order by count(*) desc, cc.minor_category limit 1)
```

I tried do something like this:

```
 db.crimes.aggregate({ 
$group: {
    "_id": {
        year: "$year", 
        minor_category :"$minor_category", 
        count: {$sum: "$minor_category"} 
     } 
   },
}, 
{
    $match : {
           minor_category: ?
    }
})
```

But i stuck in $match which is equivalent to having, but i dont know how to make subqueries in mongo like in my sql query.

Can anybody can help me ?

Comment: From the SQL query it seems that there are many minor_category in a given year and the subquery is getting the minor_category with the highest count in a particular year. So finally , the output is for every  year get the minor_category with the highest count. Please confirm my understanding is correct ?

Comment: @mintekhab Exactly it is it !

Comment: @MateuszZ answered below . Query is a little big to fit in comment section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok based on the confirmation above , the below query should work.

```
db.crime.aggregate
([
  {"$group":{"_id":{"year":"$year","minor":"$minor"},"count":{"$sum":1}}},
  {"$project":{"year":"$_id.year","count":"$count","minor":"$_id.minor","document":"$$ROOT"}},
  {"$sort":{"year":1,"count":-1}},
  {"$group":{"_id":{"year":"$year"},"orig":{"$first":"$document"}}},
  {"$project":{"_id":0,"year":"$orig._id.year","minor":"$orig._id.minor","count":"$orig.count"}}
)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This translates into the following MongoDB query:

```
db.crime.aggregate({
    $group: { // group by year and minor_catetory
        _id: {
            "year": "$year",
            "minor_category": "$minor_category"
        },
        "count": { $sum: 1 }, // count all documents per group,
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        "count": -1, // sort descending by count
        "minor_category": 1 // and ascending by minor_category
    }
}, {
    $group: { // now we get the highst element per year
        _id: "$_id.year", // so group by year
        "minor_category": { $first: "$_id.minor_category" }, // and get the first (we've sorted the data) value
        "count": { $first: "$count" } // same here
    }
}, {
    $project: { // remove the _id field and add the others in the right order (if needed)
        "_id": 0,
        "year": "$_id",
        "minor_category": "$minor_category",
        "count": "$count"
    }
})
```

Comment: The SQL query metioned above uses TOP which is supported by MSSQL . Other RDBMS support Limit (postgresql). Also, for the mongo query the sort should be on year and count . Count alone will not give the required result. The limit 1 will give only one record instead of giving 1 record for each year.

Comment: Thanks, I come from a SQL background that's why I misinterpreted the query initially (and this is where the single record came from, too). I do not agree with the sorting statement, though.